Light switch intermittently trips circuit breaker when I switch the light off
The light switch in my garage works fine most of the time, but once a fortnight or so, when I switch the light off, there's a pop and sparks from the switch, and the circuit breaker trips. I replaced the switch, but the problem persists. I had the switch and its wiring checked by an electrician, who couldn't identify the fault. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? The light is a flourescent tube.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Most of the time when a light switch sparks and trips the breaker, the hot screw/wire is too close to a metal grounded box or ground wire.  Some people wrap electrical tape around the switch to cover the screws to fix this.  Possible the switch and/or box is a bit loose and moves around enough, but your situation is a bit odd.

IS this a 'normal' switch with just 2 wires (and maybe a ground wire) connected to it?

Get a better electrician. Your contractor should have checked the light and replaced the switch for you. Not identifying the fault isn't acceptable.

Tell us about or show us your hardware, please. There's not enough here to go on.

What type of breaker do you have for the circuit? Does it only trip on over-current, or does it have an AFCI or GFCI function as well?
